# Mix CABasicAnimation with CGAffineTransform animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, transform

I need to rotate an UIImageView continuously. To do this I found this code :

```
if ([self.image.layer animationForKey:@"SpinAnimation"] == nil) {

        CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2 * M_PI];
        animation.duration = 90.0f;
        animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
        [self.image.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
    }
```

Then, I need to make a transform translation on the image view, animating it. If I do this :

```
CGAffineTransform transform = self.image.transform;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, 350);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        self.image.transform = transform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        self.isMiddleViewOpened = YES;
    }];
```

When the animation is performed, the image float all around the view before arriving to the end point of the translation. 
Thanks ☺️

**EDIT**
I have issue because in my second transform I edit only the y value, but the image doesn't move only on y axis. If you try this code, you'll see the issue

Comment: what is the tranform ? does it rotate the image ?

Comment: what is wrong with your code? do u have any issues ?

Comment: I had a diiferent idea in my mind, I will post one way to do it without mixing the core animation with ui animation

Comment: That would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to mix both animations, you can use Core animation to do all your animation stuff.

I use this in my splash screen to rotate four image blocks and combine them into one in the end.

The animation would like this:

[image]

**Code for one image block:** *Top left block , I call it 00 block*

```
- (void)addSplashScreenAnimationWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completionBlock
{
    [self addSplashScreenAnimationWithBeginTime:0 andFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth andRemoveOnCompletion:NO completion:completionBlock];
}

- (void)addSplashScreenAnimationWithBeginTime:(CFTimeInterval)beginTime andFillMode:(NSString *)fillMode andRemoveOnCompletion:(BOOL)removedOnCompletion completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completionBlock
{
    CAMediaTimingFunction *linearTiming = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    if (completionBlock)
    {
        CABasicAnimation *representativeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"not.a.real.key"];
        representativeAnimation.duration = 8.500; //your duration
        representativeAnimation.delegate = self;
        [self.layer addAnimation:representativeAnimation forKey:@"SplashScreen"];

    }

    CAKeyframeAnimation *_00RotationAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    _00RotationAnimation.duration = 8.500;
    _00RotationAnimation.values = @[@(0.000), @(18.829), @(18.829)];
    _00RotationAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0.000), @(0.353), @(1.000)];
    _00RotationAnimation.timingFunctions = @[linearTiming, linearTiming];
    _00RotationAnimation.beginTime = beginTime;
    _00RotationAnimation.fillMode = fillMode;
    _00RotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = removedOnCompletion;


    CAKeyframeAnimation *_00OpacityAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    _00OpacityAnimation.duration = 8.500;
    _00OpacityAnimation.values = @[@(0.000), @(0.497), @(0.553), @(0.759), @(0.921), @(1.000), @(0.642), @(0.341), @(0.000), @(0.000)];
    _00OpacityAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0.000), @(0.059), @(0.118), @(0.176), @(0.235), @(0.353), @(0.471), @(0.647), @(0.765), @(1.000)];
    _00OpacityAnimation.timingFunctions = @[linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming];
    _00OpacityAnimation.beginTime = beginTime;
    _00OpacityAnimation.fillMode = fillMode;
    _00OpacityAnimation.removedOnCompletion = removedOnCompletion;


    CAKeyframeAnimation *_00ScaleXAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
    _00ScaleXAnimation.duration = 8.500;
    _00ScaleXAnimation.values = @[@(0.600), @(0.600), @(1.187), @(1.187)];
    _00ScaleXAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0.000), @(0.353), @(0.765), @(1.000)];
    _00ScaleXAnimation.timingFunctions = @[linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming];
    _00ScaleXAnimation.beginTime = beginTime;
    _00ScaleXAnimation.fillMode = fillMode;
    _00ScaleXAnimation.removedOnCompletion = removedOnCompletion;

    CAKeyframeAnimation *_00ScaleYAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"];
    _00ScaleYAnimation.duration = 8.500;
    _00ScaleYAnimation.values = @[@(0.688), @(0.688), @(1.359), @(1.359)];
    _00ScaleYAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0.000), @(0.353), @(0.765), @(1.000)];
    _00ScaleYAnimation.timingFunctions = @[linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming];
    _00ScaleYAnimation.beginTime = beginTime;
    _00ScaleYAnimation.fillMode = fillMode;
    _00ScaleYAnimation.removedOnCompletion = removedOnCompletion;


    CAKeyframeAnimation *_00TranslationXAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
    _00TranslationXAnimation.duration = 8.500;
    _00TranslationXAnimation.values = @[@(0.000), @(107.423), @(211.936), @(211.936)];
    _00TranslationXAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0.000), @(0.353), @(0.765), @(1.000)];
    _00TranslationXAnimation.timingFunctions = @[linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming];
    _00TranslationXAnimation.beginTime = beginTime;
    _00TranslationXAnimation.fillMode = fillMode;
    _00TranslationXAnimation.removedOnCompletion = removedOnCompletion;


    CAKeyframeAnimation *_00TranslationYAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    _00TranslationYAnimation.duration = 8.500;
    _00TranslationYAnimation.values = @[@(0.000), @(390.498), @(476.237), @(476.237)];
    _00TranslationYAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0.000), @(0.353), @(0.765), @(1.000)];
    _00TranslationYAnimation.timingFunctions = @[linearTiming, linearTiming, linearTiming];
    _00TranslationYAnimation.beginTime = beginTime;
    _00TranslationYAnimation.fillMode = fillMode;
    _00TranslationYAnimation.removedOnCompletion = removedOnCompletion;


}
```

The above method contains series of animations like rotating, opacity changin,,scaling along x and y axis,translating along x and y axis.
You need to subclass the `UIImageView` or `UIView` and put the animation in there.

You can call the above method like:

```
 //Here _splashView can be UIView or UIImageView

[_splashView addSplashScreenAnimationWithCompletion:^(BOOL finished) {

      //Do your stuff after animation is completed
}];
```

You can use `repeatCount` for `CAKeyFrameAnimation` too, and you should give `HUGE_VALF` to get the infinity time rotation.

Comment: So, the key is to use CAKeyframeAnimation? But my image has to rotate all the time, but to translate on its y axis when my view is opened and return to its position when my view is closed. How can I implement this? I'm a little confused

Comment: Based on my requirement , I rotated the image upto some extent, you can rotate  your image forever!!! So when you open your view, the image has to be moved to certain position with rotation ?

Comment: u can use repeatCount for CAKeyFrameAnimation too, and you should give HUGE_VALF to get the infinity time rotation.

Comment: Yes, the image has to continue the rotation while moving to another position. Then, when the view is closed the image has to return to the original position, while rotate. The fundamental thing is the image has to rotate always.

Comment: The image is also tappable, so I recognize the tap on the image view and show a full screen version of that image. I noticed that when I move the image with the transform the tappable area remains the original frame and not the new layer position. I know with a transform the frame remains the same, but how can I avoid this? I need to move all the view while it rotates, I tried edit the constraint, but with no effect.